# Django many-to-many self, but not self

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have a django model which needs to link to other models of the same type, thus:

```
class Foo(Models.model):
    ...
    related_link = models.ManyToManyField('self', default=None, blank=True, null=True, related_name="related_link_record")

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ['related_link']
```

This works nicely. But, it would be useful if in the admin interface one could be prevented from linking a particular instance of Foo to itself. One way I thought of doing this is as follows:

```
def check_related_link(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print "Just saved ", str(instance)
    for rel in instance.related_link.all():
        if rel.id == instance.id:
            print "Removing {0} from related links for {1}".format(str(rel),str(instance))
            instance.related_link.remove(rel)

signals.post_save.connect(check_related_link, sender=Foo)
```

This code runs after saving and claims to be removing the related link but no such removal occurs.

Can anyone suggest what I've got wrong in the above or, better still, a means of filtering out the same instance within the admin interface?

Answer (score 0):

Chenge to `instance.related_link.remove(rel)` instead of `instance.related_link.remove(link)`

There is no link, replace link with rel.

Comment: Please accept my apologies - the code is in fact correct (it does have rel in it), I have made a mistake when typing it in here.